# Flex - modal transparency blur only on certain components when using PopUpManager?

Tags: apache-flex, popup, modal-dialog, modalpopups

When using the PopUpManager in Flex with modal = true, the background application is blurred.  Is it possible to keep this blur for most of the background application but set certain components to not be blurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll need to create this type of custom functionality - the modal screen is either on or off.

Sorry for the bad news  :\